# Move focus from one input to other input in react js when max length is full of first input

Tags: reactjs, react-router

move focus from one input to other input in react js when max length of first input is full

```
<div className="col-2">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" className="form-control text-center" maxLength={1} ref={this.vc1} returnkeytype={'next'} value={this.state.v1} onSubmitEditing={this.maxLength?1:() => this.focusNextField('2')} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-2">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" className="form-control text-center" maxLength={1} ref={this.vc2} returnkeytype={'next'}  value={this.state.v2} onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.focusNextField('3')}/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

## List item

Comment: `onSubmitEditing` sounds like *react-native*, not *reacjs* - did you mean `onChange`?

Answer (score 0):

You can focus your input by using its ref.

> myInputRef.focus();

You can define `focusNextField` like below.

```
focusNextField = (nextField) => {
  if (nextField === '2') {
     this.v2.focus();
  } else if (nextField === '3') {
     this.v3.focus();
  }
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea by using `refs` to help with the focusing logic. An easy way would be to keep track of an array of `refs`, and upon input change, you would update the current index that corresponds to the `ref`. Employ state to keep track of that index.

Then on `componentDidUpdate()` which is triggered on state-change, you can identify that `ref` and check to see if the length of its input-value matches its max length. If it does, then you would simply focus into the ref at the next (+1) index.

Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-fast-yo4mg

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    v1: "",
    v2: "",
    v3: "",
    currentRefIndex: null
  };

  vc1 = React.createRef();
  vc2 = React.createRef();
  vc3 = React.createRef();

  onChange = (e, index) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      currentRefIndex: index
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const refs = [this.vc1, this.vc2, this.vc3];

    const { currentRefIndex } = this.state;

    //get current ref attributes
    const currentRef = refs[currentRefIndex].current;
    const currentRefMaxLength = currentRef.maxLength;
    const currentRefValue = currentRef.value;

    if (
      currentRefValue.length === currentRefMaxLength &&
      currentRefIndex < refs.length - 1
    ) {
      refs[currentRefIndex + 1].current.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control text-center"
              maxLength={1}
              ref={this.vc1}
              returnkeytype={"next"}
              name="v1"
              value={this.state.v1}
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 0)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control text-center"
              maxLength={3}
              ref={this.vc2}
              returnkeytype={"next"}
              name="v2"
              value={this.state.v2}
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 1)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control text-center"
              maxLength={2}
              ref={this.vc3}
              returnkeytype={"next"}
              name="v3"
              value={this.state.v3}
              onChange={e => this.onChange(e, 2)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```